# UIActivityIndicator Disappear from View When app goes to the background and when switching tabs

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an issue which is not a big deal but driving me crazy. 
I have a view which subclasses UITableView.

Pressing on one of the cells leader to an lengthy HTTP requests, which I run on another thread using this code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
        case SECTION_SEND:
            [self addActivityIndicatorToView];
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(sendEmail) withObject:nil];
        break;
```

The activityIndicator is behaving correctly. Displaying on the screen and then removing itself when the operation ends. But if the app goes to the background or another tab, the activity indicator disappears, even though the task did not finish.

Here are the methods I am using:

Then:

```
-(UIActivityIndicatorView*)createActivityIndicator {
        //Setting up activity indicator
        UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
        spinner.color = [UIColor whiteColor];
        spinner.backgroundColor =  [UIColor blackColor];
        spinner.alpha = 0.8;
        CGFloat width = 120;
        spinner.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.bounds.size.width/2-width/2, self.tableView.bounds.size.height/2-width/2, width, width);
        //spinner.center = CGPointMake( [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height/2);
        spinner.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
        spinner.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        return spinner;
 }



-(void)addActivityIndicatorToView {
    //[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:ai];
    _ai = [self createActivityIndicator];
    [self.tableView.superview addSubview:_ai];
    [_ai startAnimating];
}

-(void) removeActivityIndicatorFromView {
    [_ai stopAnimating];
    [_ai removeFromSuperview];
}
```

I am calling [self removeActivityIndicatorFromView] when the operation ends. 
As I said, it behaves properly unless I leave the screen. I have check my viewdidload and viewwilldisappear viewwillappear and init methods and I have nothing overriding _ai.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try setting hidesWhenStopped on the UIActivityIndicatorView to NO.

Comment: Unfortunately not helping

Comment: I have added this code, and "still animating" is printing on the screen, but the _AI still disappears from view. 
`-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    if (_ai.isAnimating) {
        [self.tableView.superview addSubview:_ai];
        NSLog(@"Still animating");
    }
}`